# How can I move the Bootstrap Navigation Logo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble positioning my company logo on our website. It is too low and looks out of alignment. Is there anyway to move the logo up? Or is there a way to set the logo so that there is the same amount of space in between the top and bottom of the nav and image?

Here is the JSFiddle link: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/9351e7nb/1/)

```
<!-- Nav Branding -->   <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img width="30" height="30" src="http://www.edcodie.com/logo.png"></a>
```

Here is what I have:
[image: Logo needs moved up a bit]

Also, my navbar shrinks when you scroll down past the second page. Is there a way to expand/shrink the logo with the nav? I included my JS for the nav shrink/expand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `padding-top` attribute of the `navbar-brand` anchor.

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/degoeym/r4bgs72e/)**

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: No problem. Also, was all the CSS in your Fiddle from the CSS file for Bootstrap? You can just choose to use jQuery 2.1.0 in JS Fiddle, then check the box to use Bootstrap. Or you can add the CDN refference links as External Resources by selecting that option on the left as well. Or you can use Bootply instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can change padding-top from here. About nav shrink bootstrap have own theme which you can use http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/grayscale/
here is tutorial and download files

Comment: where do I change padding-top at? it is set in CSS now but I can't find it.

Comment: BTW, I am actually using that template. My nav bar already extends and shrinks. I was asking if there is a way to have your logo extend and shrink with the nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

fix padding for `.navbar-brand`.